# Adding a delay between webservice calls in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, polling

I am developing a simple web app that sends a big file to a server for processing. Processing may take a quite of a time that exceeds server timeout that i can't tune, so i decided to design two services - one sends data to a server, another one constantly checks processing result. But it seems like that constant checking takes too much resources and browser starts to slow down. Here's the code:

```
      try {
        this.processService.processData(this.byteArray); //data sent for a processing

        const processingResult: ProcessResult = new ProcessResult();
        processingResult.traces = []

        do {
          this.processService.getResult().then(result => processingResult.traces = result?.traces);
        } while (processingResult.traces.length === 0);

        this.traces = processingResult.traces;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }
```

What is the best practice to add some sort of a delay between ws calls in TypeScript? Thanks.

Comment: Did you search "RxJS polling"? There are quite a few options.

Comment: If you are working with Observables. Check:  https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend `interval` in combination with `skipWhile` and `take`.

```
// SERVER

let ready = false;

function veryLongServerRequest(): void {
  timer(10000).subscribe(
    () => ready = true,
  );
}

function isServerReady(): Observable<boolean> {
  return of(ready);
}

// CLIENT

veryLongServerRequest();

interval(500).pipe(
  tap(i => console.log('Polling try ' + i)),
  switchMap(() => isServerReady()),
  skipWhile(b => !b),
  take(1),
).subscribe(() => console.log('FINISHED!'));
```

See working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-fqbwon?file=index.ts

**Edit:** You can simplify `skipWhile` + `take` to `first`

See working Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-tc2ztd?file=index.ts

Comment: Thank you very much, lady! Worked like a charm. Please, suggest a following: what if isServerReady() method provides some text feedback, not only boolean outcome, how should i modify this code to use the returned value after interval() block?

Comment: Fugured it out: changing .subscribe(() => console.log('FINISHED!')); to .subscribe(result => console.log(result));

Answer (score 3):

```
delay(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Use the above method as an async function call

```
async searchSomething() {
    // webservice call 1
    await this.delay(1000);
    // webservice call 1 
}
```